# Save output file with the same name as the directory it is in

Tags: powershell

I have a script to merge pdf's if they are in the same folder. I am trying to change the name of the final merged pdf to the name of the directory it is in but I am not familiar with powershell. Can anyone assist?

```
$PDFtk = "C:\pdktk\pdftk.exe"
$inputfolder = "C:\pdftest"
$outputfile = "combined_file.pdf"

dir $inputfolder -r -include *.pdf -exclude $outputfile | sort-object | group DirectoryName |  
% {& $PDFtk $_.group CAT OUTPUT "$($_.Name)\$outputfile" verbose}
```

End Result:

```
pdftest\
   Folder 1\
     1.pdf
     2.pdf
     3.pdf
     Folder 1.pdf <--merged pdf
   Folder 2\
     4.pdf
     5.pdf
     Folder 2.pdf <--merged pdf
```

Comment: does pdftk.exe take 'fullname' for the input & output arfuements?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to move the `$outputfile` assignment to inside your `%` loop. I also separated getting folders, from getting files inside each folder. There are now two 'Get-ChildItem' commands (or `dir`):

```
$PDFtk = "C:\pdktk\pdftk.exe"
$inputfolder = "C:\pdftest"

Get-ChildItem $inputfolder -Recurse | ? {$_.PSIsContainer } | % {
   $currentfolder = $_
   $outputfile = "$($currentfolder.Name -split '\\' | Select -Last 1).pdf"
   Get-ChildItem $currentfolder.FullName -Exclude $outputfile | ? {$_.Extension -ieq ".pdf"} | % {
      & $PDFtk "$($currentfolder.FullName)\$($_.Name)" CAT OUTPUT "$($currentfolder.FullName)\$outputfile" verbose
   }
}
```

Comment: What about folders within the $inputfolder? I don't want the $inputfolder name but the folder that the pdf's are in.

Comment: Hmm, when I run that updated code nothing happens. I changed the inputfolder to point to mine but still nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why, but `-Include` was not working so that is changed. I'm also not sure on the parameters of the program pdftk - assume its "<file> CAT OUTPUT <new file> verbose"?

Comment: This latest addition does give me a file called Report 1.pdf but it looks like it only contains 3.pdf. Instead of taking all of the pdfs like it used to do and merge them into one it takes one at a time and creates a pdf, and since 3.pdf is the last one it ends up with that one. I will need to play around with this further to see if I can get it to combine all within the folder again. I do appreciate all the help you have given me.

Comment: From looking at your question, and also @ysmtd's answer, it looks like the program takes a list of files to concat and doesn't cat each file in sequence like I thought. Honestly, I would use @ysmstd's answer, and instead of `-Include *.pdf` use `| ? {$_.Extension -ieq ".pdf"}` (I couldn't get Include to work properly either).

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work fine:

```
$pdftk = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe'
$root  = 'E:\posh\test'

gci $root -Include *.pdf -Recurse |
group DirectoryName |
% {
  $dir = gi $_.Name
  $al  = $_.Group | % { $_.FullName }
  $al += 'cat', 'output'
  $al += Join-Path $dir.FullName "$($dir.BaseName).pdf"
  $al += 'verbose'
  saps $pdftk $al -Wait
}
```

Comment: It can't seem to find the pdfs with this code, but I will keep investigating.

Comment: I edited the code, but did not change the original behavior.  I installed PDFtk and confirmed that it worked as expected.  In my previous code `$pdftk` was set to `'C:\pdftk\pdftk.exe'`, but in your code `$PDFtk` seems to be set to `"C:\pdktk\pdftk.exe"` which has a typo.  This might be why my code did not work :)